# Get google plus page url by user's id

Tags: google-plus

Is it possible to build url to user's page, knowing his id?
I tried something like https://plus.google.com/u/0/ but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just `https://plus.google.com/userId`. With +Google for example: https://plus.google.com/116899029375914044550.

Answer (score -1):

```
$userid = "116899029375914044550";
$url = "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/".$userid."/";
$params = array(
                'key' => 'YOURKEY'                                  
                );
$param_string = array();
foreach( $params as $key => $param ){
    $param_string[] = $key.'='.urlencode(trim($param));
}
$url = $url.'?'.implode('&',$param_string);
$ch = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt ( $ch , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , true );
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);                        
$data = json_decode($response);                     
$url = $data->url;
echo $url;
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation. Posting just raw code (especially in such a large chunk) makes a poor answer.